# ggplot always using default colour scheme

Tags: r, ggplot2

Every time I make a ggplot and try to adjust the colour gradient I am left with the default scheme.

```
sp <- ggplot(data=Foo) + geom_raster(aes(x=Var1,y=Var2,fill=value)) + labs(fill="Temperature")

sp + scale_color_gradient2(midpoint = mid, low = "blue", mid = "magenta",
                              high = "red", space = "Lab" )
```

This still produces the plot. I was expecting it to produce a plot which had the lowest value of blue and highest, red.
[image: Default colour scheme]

Comment: Try with `scale_fill_gradient2()`

Comment: This worked-thank you. Could you explain why I had to use fill instead of color here?

Comment: Because you are using the `fill` argument in `geom_raster()`. :) More generally, the `fill` argument handles how you colour the space within the geom, while `color`/`colour` handles how you colour the outline of the geom.